# CausalImpact R package - How to calculate the counter-factual time series from the output?

Tags: r, time-series

I am using the CasualImpact R package and I would like to get the counter-factual/control time series from the output after estimation. I run the following code which is basically the same as the example code on the website of the package.

```
set.seed(1)
x1 <- 100 + arima.sim(model = list(ar = 0.999), n = 100)
y <- 1.2 * x1 + rnorm(100)
y[71:100] <- y[71:100] + 10
data <- cbind(y, x1)
pre.period <- c(1, 70)
post.period <- c(71, 100)
impact <- CausalImpact(data, pre.period, post.period)
```

The the local linear trend is in

```
impact$model$bsts.model$state.contributions
```

while the coefficient draws are supposed to be in

```
impact$model$bsts.model$coefficients
```

so I run

```
trend=colMeans(impact$model$bsts.model$state.contributions[1:1000,1,1:100])
trend+mean(impact$model$bsts.model$coefficients[1:1000,2])*x1
```

to get the counter-factual time series, however this is far from the actual counter-factual time series when plotting the results with

```
plot(impact)
```

Can somebody tell me how I can get back the counter-factual time series?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The point predictions for the entire time series (both pre and post intervention) can be found at

`impact$series`

in the `point.pred` column. The counter-factual is the part of the point predictions that occur in the `post.period` portion of that column. `impact$series` provides the data for all three graphs in `plot(impact)`.